# Get app suggestions on trying to open an Epub

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

I am working on an app that allows everyone to read books like `Epub, PDF, ACSM`. I installed the app on my `IPAD` via `testflight` and then I went to safari to download a `ACSM` file and tried to open the same. 
Safari then gave me suggestions of a few app but it didn't include my app. I am not sure how this works. Any information would be very useful.

I want to have the file copied to the documents directory of my app so that the user will be able to access the same from the library section of the application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks .. I tried searching .. but dint find any relevance. I will look into it and reply back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question has been answered in the following link:

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

It solved my issue. Thanks again!